# What is a "tag" in Lua 4.0?

Tags: lua, lua-4.0

I was reading the Lua 4.0 manual and I came across this "tag" thing but I have no idea what it is referring to.

http://www.lua.org/manual/4.0/manual.html#3

That's the section where it mentions it but I still have no idea what the manual is talking about.

Comment: The way tags are described in Lua 4.0 sounds like the precursor to what we know today as metatables in Lua 5+. Is there a reason you're reading that older manual instead of lua 5.1 manual?

Comment: Yeah, scripting in an old game.

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR:** Tags are the precursor to modern-day meta-tables. Where now the event-handler-pairs are stored directly in the meta-table using normal table-manipulation, as it is a normal `table`, then we used those tags, normal though unique numbers, and special data-structures, which restricted the events we could set, and had a different interface.
One of the disadvantages of tags was they could not be garbage-collected as they were normal numbers, and thus their associated data could not either.

---

Quoting the important parts of section 3 "types and tags":

> Besides a type, all values also have a tag.
>
> Each of the types `nil`, `number`, and `string` has a different tag. All values of each of these types have the same pre-defined tag. As explained above, values of type `function` can have two different tags, depending on whether they are Lua functions or C functions. Finally, values of type `userdata` and `table` can have variable tags, assigned by the programmer (see Section 4.8). The `tag` function returns the tag of a given value. User tags are created with the function `newtag`. The `settag` function is used to change the tag of a table (see Section 6.1). The tag of userdata values can only be set from C (see Section 5.7). **Tags are mainly used to select tag methods when some events occur. Tag methods are the main mechanism for extending the semantics of Lua (see Section 4.8).**

So, think of tags as unique ids.
Every value has a tag, depending on its type:

- All values of the types `nil`, `number`, `string`, `function` (C-flavor), `function` (Lua flavor) have a type-specific tag set on the C side.
- All values of the types `table` and `userdata` have tags too, but those are set by the programmer for each value indepent from any other.

`tag` returns the tag, `settag` sets it for `table` and `userdata`, `newtag` creates a new one.

And looking at section 4.8 "tag methods", we understand that those unique ids are just used for comfortably associating all values of the same Lua type (or for `table`s and `userdata`s of the same semantic user-type) with special behavior:

> Lua provides a powerful mechanism to extend its semantics, called *tag methods*. A tag method is a programmer-defined function that is called at specific key points during the execution of a Lua program, allowing the programmer to change the standard Lua behavior at these points. Each of these points is called an *event*.
>
> The tag method called for any specific event is selected according to the tag of the values involved in the event (see Section 3). The function `settagmethod` changes the tag method associated with a given pair (tag, event). Its first parameter is the tag, the second parameter is the event name (a string; see below), and the third parameter is the new method (a function), or nil to restore the default behavior for the pair. The `settagmethod` function returns the previous tag method for that pair. A companion function `gettagmethod` receives a tag and an event name and returns the current method associated with the pair.

Which just boils down to `settagmethod` and `gettagmethod` being used to manage a mapping from tag+event to handler, and the runtime using that as an extension point.

As LHF mentions below, there's a wealth of additional detail and history in [The evolution of Lua](http://www.lua.org/doc/hopl.pdf), for example how the tag-methods evolved from the previous extension-mechanism of "fallbacks", which did not support different behavior for separate groups of values, instead being global.

Comment: See also [The evolution of Lua](http://www.lua.org/doc/hopl.pdf), especially sections 5.3 and 6.8.